# Index not turning on/changing directories

Tags: windows-7, search-indexing

I tried changing the indexing location of my index on Windows 7, but all it does is keep defaulting back to the default location. I'm trying to change it to my hard drive because Windows is installed on my SSD and I'm trying to save space. I select the new location, hit "OK" and I check it again in "Advanced" and it still shows the old location, nothing was changed. Now the whole index is turned off and won't turn back on. I press "Rebuild" and hit "OK" again. It just displays "Index is not running." What do I do now?

Comment: have you confirmed that your indexing service is running? check it in `services.msc` or run `(Get-Service WSearch).status` to find out. if it is off, try starting it. otherwise, try restarting it, and quickly checking your application log for errors.

Comment: It says the service is disabled.

Comment: in `services.msc`, right click the **Windows Search** service, `Right click -> Properties -> Startup Type, and set it to "Automatic (Delayed Start)"`. Then attempt to start the service, and check your logs if any errors occur.

Comment: Now it's back up, but it won't change directories...